# Im pushing to array by service, but its not visible Angular

Tags: angular

Im pushing im trying to push data from Reactive form in one component to service and then output this in mat-table, the problem is it works, when im cl('array','data') everything lookis fine but its not vissible from the website.

```
ts.

onSubmit() {
    const singleJob: Job = {
      name: this.signupForm.controls['jobsName'].value,
      points: this.signupForm.controls['jobPoints'].value,
    };
    this.dataService.pushToJobs(singleJob);
  }
  addUser() {
    const singleUser: User = {
      name: this.signupForm.controls['userName'].value,
    };
    this.dataService.addUser(singleUser);
  }

service.ts

export class DataService {
  jobs: Job[] = [
    { name: 'sprzatanie', points: 10 },
    { name: 'gotowanie', points: 20 },
    { name: 'mycie okien', points: 30 },
    { name: 'wyniesc smieci', points: 10 },
    { name: 'zmywanie', points: 50 },
  ];
  userJobs: Job[] = [{ name: 'test1', points: 7 }];
  users: User[] = [{ name: 'Karol' }];
  constructor(private logic: LogicService) {}

  pushToJobs(userjob: Job) {
    this.jobs.push(userjob);
    console.log(userjob, this.jobs);
  }
  pushToUserJobs() {}
  addUser(user: User) {
    this.users.push(user);
    console.log(user, this.users);
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you passing data to mat table?

Comment: by input in form
onSubmit() {
    const singleJob: Job = {
      name: this.signupForm.controls['jobsName'].value,
      points: this.signupForm.controls['jobPoints'].value,
    };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your mat-table consumes the data like this

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="userJobs>...</mat-table>
```

Your component

```
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(
    private readonly _dataService: DataService,
  ) {
    this.userJobs = this._dataService.userJobs;
  }
}
```

Given this code the problem is that mat-table stores (and updates) the array by reference. Since you just add data to the array, this reference does not change (even though its stored values may).
Therefore you should just create a new array when adding items to the existing array like so:

```
private _userJobs = [];
userJobs$ = BehaviorSubject(this._userJobs);

pushToUserJobs(userjob: UserJob) {
  this._userJobs = [...this.userJobs, userjob];
  userJobs$.next(this._userJobs);
}
```

and

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="userJobs$ | async>...</mat-table>
```

Here's a proof of concept on Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnb33i

Comment: Which is exactly what I wrote in my answer ;)

Comment: Well yes, but it still doesnt work, it still pdates in console.log, but its not vissbile on the website

Comment: Ah, got it. Of course this won't work because the service also returns a static reference, no matter its value behind. For that matter we will have to implement this through observables.

Comment: Ye and thats the issue :D im not pretty sure how can i implement the observebles this this existing data

Comment: I will create you a stackblitz. Give me a minute.

Comment: Great! You will be my hero!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnb33i?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts
Proof of concept

Comment: Im sorry to bother You buit i have last question, now it works, its changing just the problem is i can add only one new object and then even if im trying to add new on it does not work

Comment: Please double-check the implementation on Stackblitz, as it's working fine there with an `Observable` concept.

Comment: Ye this works very good, i think its something with my form, but i think i will handle that, thank You again!